# Query firebase realtime database by providing values of different combinations in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

In swift I am looking to create a flexible query function for my Firebase Realtime Database in Swift that allows users to search for items based on different combinations of the plateSeries, plateFirstChar, plateSecondChar, and plateEnding keys. Users might input values for one, some, or all of these keys, and the function should return items that match the provided values

Below is my item properties in the firebase

```
func toDictionary() -> [String: Any] {
        return [
            "plateSeries": plateSeries,
            "plateFirstChar": plateFirstChar,
            "plateSecondChar": plateSecondChar,
            "plateEnding": plateEnding,
            "price": price,
            "owner": owner,
            "ownerID": ownerID,
            "phoneNumber": phoneNumber,
            "description": description
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase